# Is difference b/w procedure and function same in every programming language in terms of concept not syntax

Tags: plsql, language-agnostic

[What is the difference between function and procedure in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between function and procedure in PL/SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql)

Comment: my question is little different buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. In PL/SQL functions return data, procedures do not. In C for example both are called functions.