# Revisting ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name for simple function call via various database tools

Tags: sql, oracle, function, oracle-sqldeveloper, dbeaver

Revisting ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name for simple function call via dbeaver database-tool

I have seen many posts, but they don't cover the situation I am experiencing.

I am trying to do a simple function call to Oracle SQL via dbeaver:

According to the right-click call function obtained via dbeaver the function syntax it is:

```
CALL OUR_DB.GET_YEAR_FROM_DATE(:INPUT_DATE);
```

To be more concrete:

```
CALL OUR_DB.GET_YEAR_FROM_DATE('01/02/2024');
```

However, I get the following error:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

The function *does* seem to compile correctly.

I also tried to make my own function (which may have syntax errors), so that may be a follow-up question.

However, the above function is pre-existing on our database and should work correctly.
Assuming that is true, how does one call it from dbeaver?

I am using:
dbeaver 21.3

and also the ORACLE from SELECT * FROM v$version is:
Oracle Database 19c Standard Edition 2 Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

For what it's worth, I used Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.4.21
There is a very similar error, possibly a more detailed error message:

```
CALL OUR_DB.GET_YEAR_FROM_DATE('01/02/2024');

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
06576. 00000 -  "not a valid function or procedure name"
*Cause:    Could not find a function (if an INTO clause was present) or
           a procedure (if the statement did not have an INTO clause) to
           call.
*Action:   Change the statement to invoke a function or procedure
```

This would seem to indicate that the problem is not really due to the tool, but the underlying database.

If the syntax is thought to work, could it just be a permissions issue?

Comment: The error message is clear: "Could not find a **function** (if an **INTO clause was present**) or
           a **procedure** (if **the statement did not have an INTO clause**) to
           call."

Comment: Function returns a value. It should have a place where to return that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a substantial difference between the *function* and *procedure*.

Both get *parameters*, but only *function*  `returns` a value.

So basically a *function* can be called in a `select` statement or in a PL/SQL block in an assign statement. See example below.

Only a *procedure* can be simple called as you do it.

Some elementar information abour *functions* and *procedures* and their *distinctions*:

[what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql)

[functions-vs-procedures-in-oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419629/functions-vs-procedures-in-oracle)

**Examples**

```
create function hello(par varchar2) return varchar2  as
begin
   return ('world ' || par);
end;
/

-- wrong usage of function
CALL  hello('hello')
SQL Error [6576] [65000]: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name

-- legal use of function in SELECT
select  hello('hello') from dual;
world hello

-- or in PL/SQL block

-- use Ctrl+Shift+O  for SET serveroutput ON;
DECLARE
  v_result varchar(100);
BEGIN
     v_result := hello('helo');
     dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
END;
```

Comment: Although your works, and I accepted the answer, this is not typically what one sees in most websites, manuals and tutorials. Therefore, please add a link to such a tutorial to the top of your answer

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I added this information @JosephDoggie . I somehow assumed this must be obvious, which is of course *not true*.

Comment: Very nice add on.

Comment: While this answer may help people with a system similar to mine, it seems from internet research that on many Oracle systems, one just does a "call", but that doesn't work on my own system.