# ORA-00904 when executing package from SELECT

Tags: oracle, security, plsql, plsqldeveloper

trying to setup a specific security test case. The idea was to create a package that could be called from PL/SQL using a select statement. The package works and creates the table but when I run  `SELECT evil_pkg.CreateTab() FROM DUAL` in Oracle SQL Developer I get

> ORA-00904: "EVIL_PKG"."CREATETAB": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 41 Column: 8

Is there any way this is possible to do? 
The aim here is to execute the package in this particular way, not just to 
execute the package.

This is the package:

```
--Specification
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE evil_pkg AS
  PROCEDURE CreateTab;
END evil_pkg;
/

--Body 
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY evil_pkg AS

  PROCEDURE CreateTab
AS 

BEGIN 

 execute immediate 'CREATE TABLE my_evil_table (id number) ';

      COMMIT ; 

EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISE;

        END CreateTab;

END evil_pkg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure inside a package cannot be called from SQL.

If you convert your procedure into a function (that returns maybe a true or false or returns a value) then that can be called from sql.

You can see the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql) here as well to further your understanding.