# if procedure and function are same in plsql then why we need to go function

Tags: sql, plsql

I want to know,if procedure and function both return the value in plsql so why we need to go function in plsql.

Answer (score 0):

The function and procedure is not the samething .
Please refer the below link for reference.
[What is the difference between function and procedure in PL/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Procedures and Functions are not same 
there are lot of difference please find below one simple one for better understanding

**Function**

Select substr('abc',1,2) from dual - is possible

**Procedure**

Select sample_procedure('abc') from dual - is not possible