# How do I create a function which Inserts values in 3 tables separately. Those values are coming from some other procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to create a function that can Insert in table1, table2, Table3. 
It has to be called from some other procedure and values will be coming from that procedure.

Comment: `Want to create a function..` so what's stopping you?

Comment: Do some search, try something and then, if you have a problem with your code, feel free to post it here to have some help.

Comment: Do you mean the same values into different tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not clear. In general you can create a function which accepts as parameters the values you want to insert in the 3 tables and which  will have 3 insert statements (one for each table), assuming no dependencies like FKs between the 3 tables.

```
create FUNCTION my_function (p_value_11 NUMBER ,p_value_12 varchar2 ,p_value_21 NUMBER ,p_value_31 NUMBER)
   RETURN NUMBER
AS
v_result number := 0;

BEGIN

INSERT into my_table_1(col_11,col_12) values (p_value_11,p_value12);
INSERT into my_table_2(col_21) values (p_value_21);
INSERT into my_table_3(col_31) values (p_value_31);

RETURN v_result;
exception 
when others then
v_result  := -1;
   RETURN v_result;
END;
```

Why does it need to be a function and not a procedure?

Comment: I believe this should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: You are correct, I have edited my reply to include an example

Comment: @E.Ninis- Thank you for sharing the example. I am not sure if it should be a function or procedure. Can you please share an example of procedure as well?

Comment: Search is your friend!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771949/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-procedure-in-pl-sql

Comment: Why you wanted a function here..Your need is for a procedure inturn.

Comment: @E.Ninis - a procedure example would look the same but it would say `create procedure` and there would be no `return` clause.